# Ocultar o mostrar div al editar un formulario

Tags: jquery

quisiera me puedan ayudar con esta duda y como solucionarla.  Tengo 2 div, el segundo div viene oculto dependiendo de lo que seleccione en el primer div, hasta ahí todo bien, porque puedo ocultar o mostrar los div.

```
<div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for=""> Tiene Seguro</label>
                                    <select name="seguro" id="seguro">
                                        <option value="1" @if($user->seguro==1) selected @endif>SI</option>
                                        <option value="2" @if($user->seguro==2) selected @endif>NO</option>
                                    </select>
                                 </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

<div class="row" id="tipoSeguro" style="display:none">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="form-check">
                                        <label class="form-check-label"><input  class="form-check-input" name="tipo" type="radio" value="1" @if($user->tipo_seguro==1) checked @endif>Médico - Dental</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check">
                                        <label class="form-check-label"><input class="form-check-input" name="tipo" type="radio" value="2" @if($user->tipo_seguro==2) checked @endif>Otros</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function (){
        $('#seguro').append(function (){

            if($(this).val()==1){
                $('#tipoSeguro').show();
            }else if($(this).val()==2){
                $('#tipoSeguro').hide();
            }else if($(this).val()==""){
                $('#tipoSeguro').hide();
            }

        });
     });
</script>
```

Mi problema viene cuando quiero editar el formulario y el div que debe mostrarse se muestra o se oculta, pero si cambio la opción del select seguro por SI, debería desplegarse el div oculto, antes lo tenía con un click(function()), pero no me hacia nada si el select seguro era SI, no se mostraba, lo cambie por el append, pero ahora no cambia si seleccionó Si o NO.

Ayuda, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que yo haria es cambiar la forma en que ocultas el div, y cuando preguntes para mostrar o ocultar utiliza el fadeIn (mostrar) y fadeOut (ocultar)

```
<div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for=""> Tiene Seguro</label>
                                <select name="seguro" id="seguro">
                                    <option value="1" @if($user->seguro==1) selected @endif>SI</option>
                                    <option value="2" @if($user->seguro==2) selected @endif>NO</option>
                                </select>
                             </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

<div class="row" id="tipoSeguro" @php echo ($user->seguro==2)?'style="display:none"':''; @endphp>
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <label class="form-check-label"><input  class="form-check-input" name="tipo" type="radio" value="1" @if($user->tipo_seguro==1) checked @endif>Médico - Dental</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <label class="form-check-label"><input class="form-check-input" name="tipo" type="radio" value="2" @if($user->tipo_seguro==2) checked @endif>Otros</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


<script>
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('#seguro').change(function (){

        if($(this).val()==1){
            $('#tipoSeguro').fadeIn();
        }else if($(this).val()==2){
            $('#tipoSeguro').fadeOut();
        }else if($(this).val()==""){
            $('#tipoSeguro').fadeOut();
        }

    });
 });
```

Espero que te ayude mi respuesta

Comment: Gracias Karli, me funciono super bien

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a utilizar **"change"** en vez de **"append"**. Ya que el método **"change"** detecta el cambio de valor del elemento que selecciones, y este puede interactuar con cualquier elemento que contenga un valor y que este valor pueda verse alterado en cualquier momento. Entonces quedadaria así tu codigo:

```
<div class="row" id="tipoSeguro">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="form-check">
                    <label class="form-check-label"><input  class="form-check-input" name="tipo" type="radio" value="1" @if($user->tipo_seguro==1) checked @endif>Médico - Dental</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <label class="form-check-label"><input class="form-check-input" name="tipo" type="radio" value="2" @if($user->tipo_seguro==2) checked @endif>Otros</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

 <select name="seguro" id="seguro">
    <option selected>---</option>
    <option value="1">SI</option>
    <option value="2">NO</option>
 </select>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function (){
        $('#tipoSeguro').hide(); //Ocultas el div

        $('#seguro').on("change", function (){

          var otr= event.target.value; //otr tomara el value que tenga cada etiqueta <option>

            if(otr==1){
                $('#tipoSeguro').show();
            }else if(otr==2){
                $('#tipoSeguro').hide();
            }
        });
     });
</script>
```

El problema que venias teniendo y que el cual no me había percatado era que tenias un **style="display:none"** en el div con el id="tipoSeguro", por lo tanto sin importar lo que se hicieses en el script siempre iba a tener un display oculto. Espero ahora si te sirva, avisame cualquier cosa ;)

Comment: Gracias amigo por responder, he cambiado a la opcion change, pero si mi select seguro es SI, no me muestra el div oculto :'(

Comment: Edite mi respuesta de acuerdo a tu comentario de que: no se muestra el div oculto, espero que con los cambios que hice te funcione, cualquier cosa me avisas ;)

Comment: Agradezco tu ayuda, pero lamentablemente sigue persistiendo le problema de que si la opcion es SI, el div oculto no lo detecta y no aparece

Comment: Ya era cuestión de honor jajaja, no me había percatado del "display=none" que le habías dado al div. edite la respuesta con la solución, espero te sirva

Comment: Aún sigue de la misma manera, cambie por lo que me dices y sigue sin mostrarse el div oculto

Comment: Yo lo probe y a mi me funciona sin problema https://mega.nz/#!GbonnKwA!U5OFF26fBoXcz8VyrtmpLPHF8L4wYhgdc0zk32fytHQ

Comment: Si amigo, muchas gracias, me di cuenta que funciona bien, pero creo que tengo una librería de jquery que no me esta permitiendo hacer esto y choca con el código que tu me has implementado :'(.  Sigo buscando cual es mi error, ya que estoy trabajando bajo un template de Bootstrap 4

Comment: Si te funcion, puedes marcarme como la respuesta correcta, un abrazo, cualquier otra duda o si necesitas ayuda, avísame

Comment: Gracias Juan por tu ayuda